# Unable to communicate with secure web proxy on iOS 8

Tags: iphone, network, ios, proxy

I am attempting to connect to a web proxy server using the [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) proxy application installed on Windows.

I have two iPhones - an iPhone 5 running iOS 8.0.2 and an iPhone 4 running iOS 7.1.2.

I have used both of these phones to connect to my proxy server (both HTTP and HTTPS) for a while now, but this is the first time I have tried to connect the iPhone 5 following the iOS 8 update.

I can connect to secure and insecure on my iPhone 4, but my iPhone 5 does not allow HTTPS and gives me this error:
[image]

I have tried [installing the SSL certificate](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/) again on my iPhone 5, but this has had no effect.

Both phones have identical network configuration and I *can* communicate with the proxy on the iPhone 5 - just not over SSL.

The Charles error is:
`SSLHandshake: Remote host closed connection during handshake`

Comment: We are seeing the exact same thing with out Blue Coat proxies that perform SSL interception. We do not have a resolution.

Comment: I am unfortunately successfully using my iOS 8 with SSL through Charles. Can you try SSL Proxying on https://*.facebook.com/ and see whether that works in Safari on your iOS 8 device? I'm wondering if it's particular sites that are problematic. When it doesn't work on your iOS 8 device, are there any messages in Charles about what is failing? Perhaps also check the Error Log screen.

Comment: I have just tried going to https://www.facebook.com and I get the same message, this time I am using my iPad with iOS 8. Where is the Error Log screen in Charles?

Comment: @SameHere Did you have luck with a solution? Do you use Charles too? I'm still having the problem on both my iPad 2 and iPhone 5 - both of which are running iOS 8.

Comment: Perhaps [selecting another proxy](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/48403/5472) might help?

Comment: This is the error I see in Charles: `SSLHandshake: Remote host closed connection during handshake`

Comment: After **zero** response from Charles support channel I ditched it and moved to Fiddler and followed the instructions here (http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForiOS) to configure it for iOS 8 and it works well.

Comment: For me, the problem is solved by resetting the settings (General > Reset > Reset Settings). It reset ALL settings, but keep the data (apps, text messasges, etc...)

Comment: @user93183 - what version of SGOS are you using on your Bluecoats? I believe the problem here could be the accepted cipher suites. We have older versions running in our lab that don't support newer protocols such as TLS 1.2 and such, which the newer versions of SGOS do support.  A possible answer to the actual question could be to update your accepted cipher suites (disable SSL v2.0 and 3.0, which it may be trying to default to, and enable only TLS).

Comment: @WaltyYeung Are you saying you had to reset your phone to get this working. (☉_☉)

Comment: @crmpicco no, Walty Yeung said, that he solved the problem by *only* resetting the *settings*. That means he did NOT reset the whole iPhone with all the data. Go to `Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Settings` and **NOT** `Delete all Data & Settings`

Answer (score 1):

For me, Charles Proxy 4.1 works better across iOS devices.

- https://www.charlesproxy.com

You might want to reset all network settings on any iOS device you have issues with and potentially do a clean wipe if you have pinned / trusted certificates that are conflicting with the ones you need for the man in the middle proxy to work.